# What is the correct format of BatchGetBuilds parameters for 'AWS CDK - StepFunction - CallAwsService'

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, aws-step-functions

I'm working for a state machine by CDK. 
And getting an issue to check the codebuild project status in the state machine...

**Q. Could you let me know the correct format of `batchGetBuilds` parameters in `CallAwsService`?**

[image]

```
import { CallAwsService } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions-tasks"
import { JsonPath } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions"

new CallAwsService(scope, "Check 1-1: Codebuild Status", {
        service: "codebuild",
        action: "batchGetBuilds",
        parameters: {
            Ids: [JsonPath.stringAt("$.results.codebuild.id")],
        },
        iamResources: ["*"],
        inputPath: "$",
        resultSelector: { "status.$": "$.builds[0].buildStatus" },
        resultPath: "$.results.bulidAmi",
    })
```

I tried 2 ways.

1. `JsonPath.stringAt("$.results.codebuild.id")`
   Then it returns below and execution be failed.

```
"An error occurred while executing the state 'Check 1-1: Codebuild Status' (entered at the event id #9). 
The Parameters '{\"Ids\":\"******-generate-new-ami-project:05763ec2-89a6-4b56-8b44-************\"}' could not be used to start the Task:
[Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_STRING token]"
```

2. `[JsonPath.stringAt("$.results.codebuild.id")]`
   If I use array, it is failed in the build stage... (I'm using cdk pipeline to deploy this) 
   error message is below

```
Cannot use JsonPath fields in an array, they must be used in objects
```

+ Extra Question

I found this during the search
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978385/aws-step-functions-wait-for-codebuild-to-finish


Can I use this `sync` on the `CallAwsService`? (Main 1... state is using `CallAwsService` also) 
If yes, how can I use it..?
Or do I need to change the `CallAwsService` to `CodeBuildStartBuild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you let me know the correct format of batchGetBuilds parameters in CallAwsService?

Use the `States.Array` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html). These CDK syntaxes are equivalent:

```js
parameters = {
  'Ids.$': 'States.Array($.results.codebuild.id)',
  Ids: JsonPath.stringAt('States.Array($.results.codebuild.id)'),
  Ids: JsonPath.array(JsonPath.stringAt('$.results.codebuild.id'))
}
```

> Can I use this `sync` on the `CallAwsService`?

No.  The `CallAwsService` task implements the [AWS SDK service integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html), which does not support `.sync` for CodeBuild actions.  As of v2.15, CDK should throw an error if you pass the `RUN_JOB` (= `.sync`) pattern to `CallAwsService`.  See this [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19174) for context.

> Or do I need to change the `CallAwsService` to `CodeBuildStartBuild`?

Yes. [CodeBuildStartBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.CodeBuildStartBuild.html) works as expected with the `RUN_JOB` integration pattern.